# Get a signed id_token with PHP

Tags: php, azure-active-directory

I'm developing a website for a client. The users of this website are required to log in via Azure AD. Once a signed id token is issued by Azure, I am to send this id token to an endpoint provided by the client (Azure logic app). If the token is accepted, the user is logged in.

I am new to Azure (I'm a PHP dev, and I'm finding the whole thing a bit daunting, tbh). Currently I'm using this library: https://github.com/TheNetworg/oauth2-azure

I can get an id_token using the code on the github page, but that token is unsigned ("alg=none").

Is there a more suitable library? Am I going at it all wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The thing you are doing wrong is that you are using an ID token for authorization. It is not its purpose. You should be acquiring an _access token_ for the target API, which they can validate and authorize. The ID token is only meant for the app that signed in the user, to give them the identity.

Comment: Well, they want me to send an id token specifically, not an access token. Quote: "Please check that the token's aud value corresponds to the client id, to make sure it is a valid id token."

Comment: Yeah... That's not right. You can acquire an access token with their client id as the resource to get a token that has the correct audience.